# Calling CSS file and boostrap CSS file causes page to display wrongly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I read about bootstrap and thought about adding those glyphicons that they have to my file; however, whenever I try to link the boostrap.min.css file it breaks the table that I already formatted using another CSS file. Is there something I'm missing...completely new to bootstrap and just familiaring myself further with CSS in general.

Here's the part where I link the two CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/listStyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Note: the glyphicon does appear it just seems to mess with my already setup table

Edit: By break I mean it seems to be adding another column in my div table thus pushing every other column beside it to the right by 1 column

Table Code:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
<div class = "headingRow">
    <div class = "companyName"><b>Company Name</b></div>
    <div class = "address"><b>Address</b></div>
    <div class ="telNo"><b>Telephone <br/>Number</b></div>
    <div class ="faxNo"><b>Fax Number</b></div>
    <div class = "email"><b>Email</b></div>
    <div class ="website"><b>Website</b></div>
    <div class = "acronym"><b>Acronym</b></div>
    <div class = "editAction"><b>Action</b></div>
</div>$i = 0;           
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<div class = 'row' name = ".$i.">";
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<div class = 'companyNameCell'>".trim($row['name'])."</div>";
    $name = $row['name'];   
    echo "<div class = 'addressCell'>".trim($row['address'])."</div>";      
    $address = $row['address'];
    echo "<div class = 'telNoCell'>".trim($row['telNum'])."</div>";
    $telNum = $row['telNum'];
    echo "<div class = 'faxNoCell'>".trim($row['faxNum'])."</div>";
    $faxNum = $row['faxNum'];
    echo "<div class = 'emailCell'>".trim($row['email'])."</div>";
    $email = $row['email'];
    echo "<div class = 'websiteCell'>".trim($row['website'])."</div>";
    $website = $row['website'];
    echo "<div class = 'acronymCell'>".trim($row['acronym'])."</div>";
    $acronym = $row['acronym'];

    echo "<div class = 'actCell'>";
    echo "<form id = ".$i." name='edit_company' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/Index/editInfoCompany' method = 'POST'>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'id' value = '".$id."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'name' value = '".$name."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'address' value = '".$address."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'telNum' value = '".$telNum."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'faxNum' value = '".$faxNum."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'email' value = '".$email."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'website' value = '".$website."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'acronym' value = '".$acronym."'/>";
    echo "<button  onclick='document.getElementById(".$i.").submit()'/><span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>Edit</button>";
    //echo "<div class = 'actionCell'><input type = 'submit' value = 'Edit'/></div>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "<form id = 'del".$i."' name='delete_company'  class='form-inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/delete_info/deleteInfoCompany' method = 'POST'>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'id' value = '".$id."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'name' value = '".$name."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'address' value = '".$address."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'telNum' value = '".$telNum."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'faxNum' value = '".$faxNum."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'email' value = '".$email."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'website' value = '".$website."'/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'acronym' value = '".$acronym."'/>";


    echo "<button onclick = 'return deleteRow(this)' ><span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>Deactivate</button>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    $i++;
    }

    echo "</div>";
```

Relevant listStyle CSS code

```
    #incWrap{   
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
/*  background-color: #ddd;*/
    border: 1px solid;
}

#container{
/*  border: 1px solid; */
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: table;
/*  background-color: #ddd;*/
}
.headingRow{
    display: table-row;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    background-color: #00688B;
    color: white;
}
.row{
    display: table-row;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}.email, .acronym, .companyName, .address, .telNo, .website, .faxNo, .type{
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.emailCell, .acronymCell, .companyNameCell, .addressCell, .telNoCell, .websiteCell, .faxNoCell, .typeCell{
    border-top: 1px solid;
}

.companyName{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
}
.companyNameCell{
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

.address, .addressCell
{   
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

.telNo, .telNoCell{
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

.website,.websiteCell
{
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

.faxNo,.faxNoCell
{
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

.email, .emailCell
{
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

.acronym,.acronymCell
{
    text-align: left;
    display: table-cell;
}
.editAction, .actCell{
text-align: left;
display: table-cell;
```

}

Comment: If it is not possible to add the bootstrap css alongside my other css file then is there perhaps another way implement glyphicons apart from bootstrap. I just wanted to add them since they looked quite nice

Comment: In your CSS code your very top element says `#incWrap` rather than `#wrapper` - if you look at your pasted PHP your parent div container has `id = "wrapper"`... rename either your CSS or PHP element and see whether that makes a difference. Or below that, you seem to have redefined a similar style `#container`...

Answer (score 0):

Is your base_url contain `/` at end, if not add `/` before `css/listStyle.css` and `css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: with / at the end yes...I think the links work it's just that they seem to be messing with each other's style for some reason

Answer (score 0):

As the Bootstrap file is added last any of the styles it contains will have priority over the same styles your sheet has. E.g.

`listStyle.css: tr { background-color: green; }`

then

`bootstrap.min.css: tr { background-color: red; }`

Bootstrap style will win. Unless you add `!important` to `listStyle.css` styles to override Bootstrap styles. Be careful that Bootstrap styles don't have !important either... Can get very confusing to debug!

In most cases I would recommend adding any CSS imports from places you can't really control FIRST and then your custom styles afterwards so they override previously declared styles. This is how WordPress child themes work.

Comment: I tried linking it the other way around with bootstrap being called first and it still seems to override my other CSS file

Comment: Do you have a valid Doctype?

Comment: You mean the doctype html tag portion?? I haven't actually added one of those

Comment: Try putting `!important` in your listStyle.css styles only for the styles that aren't working as expected. E.g. `p { font-weight: bold !important; }`

Comment: I tried it still nothing on the table...I'll post some code on edit